# Is AWS Fargate useful for deploying a "web" service stack?

Tags: aws-fargate

I see Fargate as a good service for deploying a Docker Compose based stack, but I was wondering if it is any good for "long-running" web services, not just ones where you need dynamic scaling and undeterminate workloads (e.g. containers that are created and die on demand).

Answer (score 0):

That depends on your use-case. ECS lets you quickly deploy containerized applications. With Fargate we don't need to manage the underlying infrastructure (say server-less approach for containers!). Fargate is suitable for long-running apps, microservices, and batch jobs.

Few of my observations on Fargate are:

- Fargate storage is ephemeral - We cannot store container data in disk such as volumes. (although Fargate provides 10 GB of volume mounts that is nonpersistent empty storage.)
- Logs can be sent to Cloudwatch using `awslogs` driver. Recently AWS announced the [support for Splunk log driver](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/05/aws-fargate-pv1-3-now-supports-the-splunk-log-driver/).
- Fargate [uses](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-networking.html) only `awavpc` network mode.
- Fargate supports environment variables. Environment variables are the only way to pass parameters to the container.